# Find me a field with these properties.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

So I am searching for a field $K$ with these properties:

$1.$ $K$ is infinite.

$2.$ $K$ is not algebraically closed.

$3.$ $K$ is algebraic over a finite field.

I do not think the answer will be a trivial one.

Comment: In 3. what do you mean by "algebraic over all finite fields"? Maybe "algebraic over all finite subfields"? And do you have tried anything yet?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension?wprov=sfla1

Comment: Algebraic means algebraic extension. I'm searching such field. I'm not finding trivial examples.

Comment: I'm sorry I edited the question

Comment: Algebraic over a finite field

Comment: In 3. it says "algebraic over *a* finite field". So do you mean, over just *some* finite field?

Comment: No algebraic over only one.

Comment: $$K=\bigcup_n{\mathbb{F}_{2^{2^n}}}?$$

Comment: @Mindlack please give me a source for further explanation.

Comment: Any book on finite field theory will show that $\mathbb{F}_{2^d}$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_{2^n}$ iff $d|n$. So my $K$ is the “limit” of an increasing sequence of fields. It is clearly infinite (it contains finite subfields of unbounded cardinality), algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_2$, and not algebraically closed since $\mathbb{F}_8$ does not embed in $K$.